# How to assign a JQuery variable value to a Laravel Blade input

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a variable(string) called "cost". If I attempt to assign it to a

```
<p class="cost"> </p>
```

it works fine. However when I attempt to assigned it to Blade generated "readonly" input I get **nothing**. I get no output of the "cost" value in the input field.  I have tried unescaping the BLade input, also tried raw JS.

```
  $(".quantity").on('change', function(){
    var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
    var num = (price * quantity);
    var cost = num.toString();
    $('.cost').html(cost);  // This will not assign the value ! 
});
```

Blade Input:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{!! Form::text('cost[0]', null ,['class'=>'form-control cost', 'readonly'=>'readonly' ]) !!}</div>
```

The source code Blade produces looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"><input class="form-control cost" readonly="readonly" name="cost[0]" type="text" value=""></div>
```

Comment: @JilsonThomas  There is no error, I just get no output of the value "cost"

Comment: "cost: does not trigger an even. "quantity' triggers the event. I just want the "cost" value being assigned to the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using `class="cost"` on input you are using `id="input"` so selector needs to be changed.

In addition you set value not html on inputs

Try

```
$('#cost').val(cost);
```

Comment: Well spotted - my bad, I had included an old version of the HTMl source. I have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks ! val(cost) did it !!